# Is the word “gordo” in “caer gordo” changed to “gorda” when talking about a woman?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, coloquialismos, méxico

I just heard a girl saying "Ella me cae gorda", but my male friends say "Ella me cayó gordo". Why did this girl said "gorda" en lugar de "gordo" if both were talking about a woman?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grammatically correct way of saying it would be, as you supposed, *Ella me cayó gorda*. The DLE says so when defining the expression ***caer gordo, da*** a otra persona within the entry for *[gordo, da](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JLSh4xE)*. That is, the grammatical gender of the adjective should match the gender of the subject. (This is irrespective of the gender of the speaker.)

I would say (and this is speculation) that your friends are using *gordo* even when the subject is feminine because they are reanalyzing the adjective as an adverb. This could be because the two most common expressions of this form (subject + dative + *caer*) employ adverbs:

- *Ella me cae bien.*
- *Él me cayó mal.*

Adverbs are invariable in gender and number. If *gordo* is being turned into an adverb, following the model of *bien* and *mal*, then it stands to reason that it won't change when the gender changes. Try listening carefully to what your friends say when the subject is plural (*Ellos / Ellas me cayeron gord...*).

This is not just a guess. In some dialects you can say, when you find someone or something disagreeable, *Me cayó fatal.* Normally *fatal* is an adjective, but in this expression it sometimes behaves like an adverb, so it doesn't change in number when the subject is plural:

- *Los mariscos me caen fatal.*
- *Me caen fatal tus nuevos amigos.*

Not everybody speaks like that (i.e. some people do say *me caen fatales*, using the "correct" plural form), but if you search online there are a lot of examples of *fatal* employed as an invariable adverb.

The same applies to *horrible* and probably a few others. So there's a pattern there.

Comment: Hello, I just asked my firend if he liked the Jonas Brothers (already knew he didn't) and he told me that "Me caen gordo", gordo remains no matter the subject!

Comment: That seems to prove my theory then. :)